# Simply Private Email

Tags: email

How do I get simply private email? I know there is a difference and a balance between privacy and security. My concern is not so much about security from black hat hackers or nation state actors. I'm just tired of being clear-cut open-pit data mined for all the regular newsletters and the sale flyers for my favorite vitamins. I don't need end to end encryption for everything, although I reserve the right to encrypt the occasional communication. I just want an email provider that doesn't read my daily mail. Is that so much to ask?

Secondly, I know that the right way to migrate my email is to individually give everyone the new address. But, is it possible to forward gmail to an intermediate address (like TrashMail) without the g-people knowing it's final forwarding address?

The reason this comes up is that I am about to make my first Linux installation. It looks like Lubuntu is a good fit for me. Uses the Thunderbird email client. I'l add on Enigmail for encryption. And yes, I'm going to learn to use a VPN. Probably using VirtualBox. (Just to keep the local ISP from scraping my data.) I simply do not want to be so completely data mined. I know that all my actions out there on the web feed the miners. I can accept that. When I go out in public I'm ready to dance. I just want my daily mail to be private. Do I really need to go full end to end encryption just to keep my daily junk mail private??

Comment: Why don't you use an ISP and email provider you trust?

Comment: This site is for recommending software; email providers are off-topic. As you seem to have the software parts figured out (GNU/Linux + Thunderbird + Enigmail), I don’t think you question is on-topic here, unless there’s something hidden which you still need?

Comment: Thunderbird will have all the add-ons you need. Now you need the right provider. TorMail and several other email providers have touted such encryption standards. I would recommend perhaps buying your own domain and hosting email with a reputable hoster (I am not familiar with this); thus allowing you to allocate your friends/family a @yourdomain email as well. Just ideas! :)

Comment: You _could_ purchase your own domain (or two) and run your own mail server(s)...

Comment: As @JeffZeitlin says... you being in control is hte only way.  Domains are $15/year, get a Linode VPS for $5/mo, and setup postfix+dovecot+mysql.  https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

Comment: ProtonMail, Tutanota and Posteo are well worth a try.

Comment: you set dns manually, use 3rd party email client, proxy, vpn, virtual machines, encrypting to keep your emails private? I don't think all these can protect you but will make things worse. You're trying to put many things between you and your mails. And I doubt if they are more trustable than the common way of reading /writing emails. I mean you won't only worry about your ISP and email provider but also the things you put among them.

Comment: Off topic: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/are-mail-service-offering-recommendations-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

"Do I really need to go full end to end encryption just to keep my daily junk mail private??"

In this age of deep-state/big government snooping, Silicon Valley giants monetizing your data, and incompetent corporations getting pwned by hackers, the short answer is: yes, you really do need end-to-end encryption. If you regularly clean out junk mail from your account or are willing to pay a subscription, I recommend Proton Mail - it solves each of the 3 problems mentioned above.

Protection against deep-state/government-sponsored snooping: Proton Mail is based in Switzerland (a politically neutral country) so it's largely safe from governmental bullying.

Protection against getting "pwned" by hackers server-side: Proton Mail stores your emails encrypted server-side and they don't store "backdoor" copies of your decryption key as part of their policy.

Protection against your data being monetized: Proton Mail is supported by premium and enterprise subscription (recurring fee) accounts rather than advertising or big data. They do offer free 500MB accounts though.

Comment: If you want end-to-end encryption, then you don't want email. You can't warrant full encryption with email.